# My Own PHP MVC Framework for learning purpose only

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I am a great fan of Zend framework and somehow i have modified it in my own way.
I have been using it from around a year but still i lack knowledge of some internal workings.
So i decided to design my own framework to understand inner things. 

**I just want from you guys to provide resources about it, articles, tutorial or any book.**
I want it to be like Zend framework and initially just MVC structure only.

Comment: MVC is a Design Pattern. Look it up in Wikipedia and follow any links it points to. Understand the pattern. Implement it. Repeat with any other Design Patterns you come across.

Comment: Zend framework is not *exactly* an MVC framework, it more or less lacks the 'M' of MVC.  I think you should read: [Don't Reinvent The Wheel, Unless You Plan on Learning More About Wheels](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/dont-reinvent-the-wheel-unless-you-plan-on-learning-more-about-wheels.html).

Comment: @evolve MVC is only about [splitting user interface interaction into three distinct roles](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html). It's main aim is separation of layers. It does not say anything about how the Model should look. It can't because the Model really is your application. V and C is just an UI to it. In that regard ZF is much more true to the pattern than all the frameworks that do have a Model class.

Comment: MVC is a buzzword. Most PHP frameworks implement "Passive-MVC" or "MVC2" or a Model-View-Presenter scheme. They just don't know.

Comment: Thanks all for your response, i already told you guys that i am using Zend for my real work. I am not reinventing the wheel, i just want to learn how the wheel was made on first place. Only for learning purposes.

Comment: So you guys please guide me so that it would be helpful for me.

Comment: Well, either start at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) or [find yourself a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mvc+php)

Answer (score 2):

one way that I have found to be very helpful in understanding the inner workings of something like Zend Framework is to use a debugger and step through the code. You can follow it is as it does each thing and really get a good feel for where it goes, what it uses and how it works.

I use the Netbeans IDE and if you have xdebug installed and configured properly you can set some breakpoints, hit debug and follow any aspect of the code as deeply or shallowly as you like. Very, very useful.

[Here is a link to doing this.](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html)

Comment: +1 Thanks, good idea. Well i use dreamweaver and firephp.

Comment: Might want to give Netbeans a try anyway. It is free and open source and the debugging is much more powerful than firephp. You might be surprised at how useful it is.